# MySQL problems after upgrading to Rails 2.3

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, upgrade

Yesterday I updated our project from Rails 2.2.2 to Rails 2.3.4 and there seem to be major problems with MySQL: a lot of slow queries (up to 100-200 seconds), very high DB latency, lock timeout errors. I had to rollback to the previous version and now trying to investigate this strange behavior. Maybe someone experienced similar issues?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced this myself but it might be worth re-installing the MySQL gem.

Comment: Tried this... with no luck :-(